# Viewport offsets when exiting fly mode

Tags: 3d-view

Everytime I exit fly mode the viewport offsets a little and it is pretty annoying when working closely to a model.

Below are two photos showing where the viewport is in fly mode and where it offsets when exiting the fly mode.
[image: Photo_in_fly_mode]

[image: Photo_exiting_fly_mode]

What is the cause of this problem and how it can be solved ? 
Thank you.

**Edit : I don't know what causes this issue but using the mouse middle button to rotate seems to reduce the offset.**

Comment: How are you exiting fly mode? When I exit with a left click, it is the same in the startup scene.

Comment: I am exiting the fly mode with a left click.Are there other options of exiting the fly mode ? I realized that the closer I am to the object the bigger the offset.

Comment: Does this happen after a factory reset? Does is happen in a clean file? If not, can you upload your file to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com? I still can't reproduce the problem. I just wanted to make sure you weren't escaping the operation with a right click.

Comment: I believe I fixed it by exiting flymode, zooming in by scrolling up, and when I tried flymode again, it was perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by switching to camera view and back to from it